# Google Chrome setting different Homepage on Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, policy, group-policy, regedit

I have a Mac and 2 Windows 7 machines. I use a local page, which is stored on the hard drive of each system, as the Homepage link.

Since I have the same Google account signed in on all three machines, I am unable to set individual homepage paths (while syncing other settings). On one windows machine I was able force the HomepageLocation attribute through Registry change in the Policy settings (HKLM/Software/Policies/Google/Chrome/HomepageLocation).

But when I tried the same on the other Windows machine, the setting was not listed as an Machine override under chrome://policy

I am not sure what is different on both Windows machines. Please suggest if I am missing something while setting the registry entry, or if there is an easier way to achieve this objective.

Thank you!